# How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`biblatex-trad`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad)

I'd like to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) while at the same time maintaining the bibliography format of the traditional BibTeX styles (`plain`, `abbrv`, `unsrt`, `alpha`). Looking at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles), some of the necessary tweaks to the styles shipped with `biblatex` seem rather straightforward, but others (e.g., shifting the location of the `pages` field for `@article` entries) are more tricky. What customizations of `biblatex` are needed to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles as closely as possible?

Here's a compilable example for the `plain` style displaying the entry types `@article`, `@book`, and `@incollection`. (The [sometimes idiosyncratic] formatting of the BibTeX database is modelled after [`xampl.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/xampl.bib) which is part of most TeX distributions.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifbiblatex

% \biblatextrue

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A+01,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc and Duthor, Dd},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {101--109},
  month = jan,
  note = {This is an article entry},
}
@book{A+02,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc and Duthor, Dd},
  title = {Title},
  volume ={1},
  series = {Series},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address = {Location},
  edition = {First},
  month = "1~" # jan,
  year = {2002},
  note = {This is a book entry}
}
@incollection{A+03,
  author = {Author, Aa and Buthor, Bb and Cuthor, Cc and Duthor, Dd},
  title = {Title},
  editor = {Zuthor, Zz and Yuthor, Yy and Xuthor, Xx and Wuthor, Ww},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  number = {1},
  series = {Series},
  chapter = {2},
  type = {Part},
  pages = {101--109},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address = {Location},
  edition ={First},
  month = jan,
  year = {2003},
  note = {This is an incollection entry},
}
\end{filecontents}

\ifbiblatex
  \usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\fi

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\ifbiblatex
  \printbibliography
\else
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Output if one uncomments `\biblatextrue`:

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that, so far at least, there are no biblatex-affiliated packages that implement the look-and-feel of the "classic" `plain`, `unsrt`, etc bibliography styles?

Comment: @Mico I'm not aware of any such packages. My answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52106/510) provides a starting point, but not a perfect emulation.

Comment: Do you mean for all traditional BibTeX entry types (e.g., `@Booklet`, `@Manual`, `@MastersThesis`, etc.)? AUCTeX gives me 14 entry types to choose from; worrying about all of them for each of the four styles seems like a fairly tedious task.  Though maybe one answer per style would make people more inclined to give it a go (especially if they are users of one of those styles and would like an easy migration route to `biblatex`).

Comment: @jon a) Tweaking `@article`, `@book`, and `@incollection` will cover most cases b) I suspect that, apart from the differences outlined in my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52106/510), the tweaks will be the same (or at least similar) for the four styles c) If nobody else comes up with an answer, I'll have a go at it.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel As you want to tackle this, note that `xampl.bib` is *not* a sufficient test file, becuase there are also differences in the treatment of multiple-author works.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

---

### I don't deprecate any testing ;-) -- all standard styles are available as biblatex styles here: [trad-biblatex](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-trad) [image: GitHub]

---

*The following remarks requires biblatex 2.0 or newer!*

The aim is to setup standard bibliography styles which allow all modifications provided by BibLaTeX. In the first step the implementation of the entry types `@BOOK`, `@ARTICLE` and `@INCOLLECTION` are on focus. The implemented styles are marked by a green check mark ;-)

## Preface

The traditional BibTeX styles are providing the following fields and entry types.

Entry types:

```
article  book  booklet  inbook  incollection 
inproceedings conference manual mastersthesis 
misc phdthesis proceedings techreport unpublished
```

fields:

```
address   author    booktitle    chapter    edition
editor    howpublished    institution    journal
key    month    note    number    organization
pages    publisher    school    series    title
type    volume    year
```

All traditional fields and entry types are provided by BibLaTeX too. However BibLaTeX offers more entry types and fields. So I recommend by using BibLaTeX to change the bib entries related to BibLaTeX.

## Modifications

The basic order and settings for all standard styles are equal. So I am providing a file `trad-standard.bbx` which yields the standard settings. The extra settings are done in the required `bbx` files.

First I collect some details of the style:

- the sorting is chronological by `AUTHOR` then `title` then `YEAR`
- Names are printed as: Firstname (no initials) Surname
- all names are printed; *et~al.* is set as a replacement of `and others` in the field
- the field `title` is printed with emphasis for the entry types:

  ```
  book  inbook  manual  phdthesis  proceedings
  ```
- the field `title` is printed as normal for the entry types:

  ```
  article  booklet  conference incollection  inproceedings
  mastersthesis  misc  techreport  unpublished
  ```
- all other fields are printed as `\normalfont`
- the journal title isn't introduced by a string `in`, excluding `@incollection`
- <sub>ordering of entries can be seen in the examples</sub>

## Style `plain` [image: Check Mark Green]

- all entries are numbered

## Style `unsrt` [image: Check Mark Green]

- equal to the style `plain`
- sorting scheme is *none*.

## Style `alpha` [image: Check Mark Green]

NOTE: requires `biber`

- standard with a label

## Style `abbrv` [image: Check Mark Green]

- equal to `plain`
- usage of abbreviation

## Usage

This current development branch can be found at github:
[biblatex-trad](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-trad) [image: GitHub]

All traditional bibliography styles can be loaded via options by the package `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[style=trad-plain]{biblatex}
```

This method allows the using of all options provided by `biblatex`. Available styles will be (not yet):

- `trad-plain` which emulated `plain`
- `trad-unsrt` which emulated `unsrt`
- `trad-alpha` which emulated `alpha`
- `trad-abbrv` which emulated `abbrv`

<sub>I hope I didn't forget any traditional style</sub>

Some technical hints will be collected in the documentation.

## Documentation [image: Check Mark Gray]

A small documentation is available at [biblatex-trad](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-trad) [image: GitHub]

## Results:

***trd-plain***

[image]

## References

1. [BiBTeXing -- btxdoc.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base)
2. [`biblatex`-manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)
3. Testfiles ;-)

Based on the example given by lockstep here the required result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had just begun a similar project (but focusing merely on plain), so your project is very welcome. Thanks! There seem to be some minor issues with your code. Shall I post comments here or on your github site?

Comment: @acr: I answered here: https://github.com/marcodaniel/trad-biblatex/issues/1

Comment: Titlecase / capitalization does not match bibtex for me. The resulting bibliography was much larger than with bibtex, too, (using the 2015 ACM SIG templates, with abbrv). :-(

Comment: I see one warning: `Macro 'in:' already defined.`