# Problem with "and" keyword translation

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

I'm trying to generate bibliography using `bibtex`. My problem is that keyword `and` is not generated to comma. I also want to put First name after Last name. (I'm using Gummi as LaTeX editor).

Document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\selectlanguage{polish}
\title{\textbf{Title}}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\lipsum
\cite{programowanie}

\bibliography{praca-dyplomowa.bib}

\end{document}
```

BibTeX:

```
@Book{programowanie,
author =        "Van Roy, P. and Haridi, S.",
title =         "Programowanie. Koncepcje, techniki i modele",
publisher =     "Wydawnictwo Helion",
year =          "2005",
address =       "Gliwice"
}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you like the reference to look like?

Answer (score 3):

Customizing a standard bibliography style isn't easy. Normally you have to modify the code of the bst-file. This special language has a small introduction in the online documentation [*Tame the BeaST*](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast) which is also via `texdoc` available. Next to the solution below I recommend the package `biblatex` which is more flexible. There is also a contribution of the standard styles   [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo/69706#69706)

<sub>I will improve the styles soon</sub>

---

You are using the style `plain` which is defined in the file `plain.bst`. The location of the file can be found via the terminal command `kpsewhich plain.bst`. In my case it's:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/plain.bst
```

Never touch the original file. So we need a copy of `plain.bst` in our working directory. I will call it `myplain.bst`. Now we can edit the file. Find the function `FUNCTION {format.names}` and replace the code by the following one:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ll}{, jj}{, ff}{~vv}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { ",~" * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Inside your document you have to use `\bibliographystyle{myplain}` and you will get the output:

[image]