# What should I types in bib file in order to get author name like "Lawless, J. F." in output

Tags: bibtex

Why when I typed "Lawless, J. F." in `bibtex`, it becomes J. F. Lawless in output? Anyone could help me on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Depending on your `.bst`/`bibliographystyle` the names are displayed "First Last" as in "Arbold Uthor" or "Last, First" as in "Uthor, Arnold". This can be changed quite easily, but we need to know the style you use. You may want to prepare a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/), so we can help you effectively.

Comment: Hi, I am using TexShop to create my bib file. The bibliography style is "plain". "Lawless" is last name and "J. F." is first name. Kindly advice. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  It is much more difficult to help you when everyone has to guess what **your** file(s) look like.

Comment: @book{lawless2003,
 Author = "Lawless, J. F.",
 Title = "Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data",
 Edition = "{S}econd",
 Publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons",
 Year = "2003"
} this is what i type in bibtex

Comment: the output become: J. F. Lawless. Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data. John Wiley & Sons, Second edition, 2003.

Comment: Do you want the first names (and middle names, if present) be rendered in full, or do you want them abbreviated down to their initials? A separate question: Do you want the citations to be numeric-style of authoryear-style? (The `plain` bibliography style only supports the former method.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With BibTeX, the output format of the names does not depend on the input file - provided they are input correctly (both `Last First` and `First, Last` are normally well formed, so are `L. First` and `First, L.` see also [Help on BibTeX names](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-23.html)) - but on the *bibliography style*, which you call by `\bibliographystyle{<name>}`.

To change the name format of `plain` from "First Last" (as in "Arnold Uthor") to "Last, First" as in "Uthor, Arnold", you will have to modify the bibliography style.

Locate `plain.bst` on your machine, use `kpsewhich plein.bst` if you cannot find it.
Copy `plain.bst` to a location LaTeX can find it, the folder where your current `.tex` document resides is not too bad an option if you do not know where to put it.
Rename the file to, say `myplain.bst`.

Open `myplain.bst` and navigate to `FUNCTION {format.names}`, you will find the following line

```
{ s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

modify it so it reads

```
{ s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

For consistency's sake it is probably a good idea to also change

```
{ editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
```

in `FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}` to

```
{ editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" format.name$ "others" =
```

Save the file.

Now instead of `\bibliographystyle{plain}` use `\bibliographystyle{myplain}` in your document.

With the modified version of `myplain.bst` the MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lawless2003,
  Author = "Lawless, J. F.",
  Title = "Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data",
  Edition = "{S}econd",
  Publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons",
  Year = "2003",
}
\end{filecontents} 


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{myplain}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

---

If you are willing to use `biblatex`, there is no need to modify any styles in the way above.

A simple `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` is enough.

Styles similar to `plain.bst` are `style=numeric` or even `style=trad-plain`, the latter tries to emulate `plain.bst` (see [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58152/35864)).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lawless2003,
  Author = "Lawless, J. F.",
  Title = "Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data",
  Edition = "{S}econd",
  Publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons",
  Year = "2003",
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For more on `biblatex` read [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), [Workflow for managing references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18848/35864) and [`biblatex` for idiots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).

Answer (score 5):

The way how names are rendered does not depend on how you input them into your `.bib` file but on the `BibTeX` bibliography style you use. That means in most cases it is totally the same if you input a name as `firstname lastname` or `lastname, firstname`, as the bibliography style decides about how it will output it and whether it will abbreviate the first name to initials or not.

Comment: Hi, I tried many times, the output is in different order with the one I input.

Comment: @Alissa This is exactly what I am trying to tell you: the output does **not** depend on the order of the input, but on the order that was defined in the bibliography style (plain in your case).

Comment: Hi Benedikt Bauer, as what I understand, if the style is set to plain, it means the references will be numbered [1], [2], etc.

Comment: @Alissa I don't really get how the numbering of the references entries relates to the ordering of first and last names of a single entry. Could you clarify?

Comment: What I trying to say is there are few standard style used like plain, unsrt, alpha and abbrv. I follow the example from Internet to create my own bibliography file, but I don't know why there is problem with author name in the output. Of course I have more than single entry, Lawless case is my example. Sorry if I make you confuse.

Answer (score 3):

Use a bib style which supports it, eg `apalike`:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lawless2003,
  Author = "Lawless, J. F.",
  Title = "Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data",
  Edition = "{S}econd",
  Publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons",
  Year = "2003",
}
\end{filecontents} 

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```