# Bibliographystyle, how to edit apalike style?

Tags: bibtex

I use

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

It is perfect to me, except for one (not so little) detail, the way authors names are displayed in the bibliography (example) :

> Dupond, P., Beh, M., ...
>
> LastName1, FirstName1, LastName2, FirstName2, ...

you will have to admit, this is completly awful to read, the point/comma thing or the use of the same separator (comma) for firstname-lastname and different authors is confusing and wrong, I would like to obtain something like that :

> P. Dupond, M. Beh, ...
>
> FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 LastName2, ...

but I don't want to change the way `apalike` manage everything else (especialy citation display `\cite`), is there any way I can achieve this? Or any other bibliographystyle that might suits my needs?

Edit 1 :
MWE under Bernard suggestion, everything worked previously, now the citation is just bold (no link) and no bibliography appears anywhere

```
\documentclass[
twoside,
a4paper,
11pt,
chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{./bib/database.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{NameDate}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Références} \markboth{Références}{Références}
\printbibliography \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Références}

\end{document}
```

bib file :

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: Cp1252

@ARTICLE{NameDate,
  author = {LName1, FName1 and LastName2, FirstName2 and LastName3, FirstName3},
  title = {title},
  journal = {journal},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {23--29},
  number = {0},
  __markedentry = {[myname:6]},
  booktitle = {booktitle},
  issn = {2212-8271},
  keywords = {keywaords},
  owner = {my name},
  timestamp = {2014.03.05},
  url = {an url}
}
```

Editor warning : Citation 'NameDate' undefiened

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`? I don't know if `apalike` is very different from `apa`, but there exists a `biblatex-apa` package and modifying some details of a bibtex style is much easier with biblatex.

Comment: Sure, I am open to suggestions, so instead of calling `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` as I didn't find `biblatex-apa` nor `apa` under `style`, `bibstyle` and `citestyle` options in `biblatex` documentation, I used `\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=author-year]{biblatex}` but i'm confused, I get all sorts of errors, my database is created with Jabref, and it doesn't seems to work properly, EDIT : I forgot to change some other code, doing it right now

Comment: Which distribution do you have? Normally, if biblatex-apa is installed, you just have to specify `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`.

Comment: [the doc](http://mirrors.linsrv.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is from 11/2013, even not mentionned in the doc, `apa` is there you are right, I have just downloaded it, trying it right now.

Comment: Post edited with a MWE not working as intended.

Comment: I see two errors in your MWE: you should write `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography` and biblatex requires to write the .bib extension.

Comment: fixed, I realized  my bibliography is empty because on the only citation from the MWE I get `citation database_reference unidentified` but the bib file hasn't change from my previous working code, and the database_reference (NameDate) is still the same, I can't understand why the citation isn't recognized. (I did compile latex>bibtex>latex)

Comment: Could you add to your post an extract of your .bib file?

Comment: First post edited

Comment: I posted a solution. Btw, if you use `biber`, it is better to encode your .bib file in UTF8 format. This will make it more portable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the APA style. It uses the `xpatch` package  to modify the `apauthor` name format. The package has a series of commands to patch most, if not all, biblatex commands.

```
    \documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

    \usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[british]{babel}

    \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \xpatchnameformat{apaauthor}{%
            {\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{name:apa:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}?}}
            {\usebibmacro{name:apa:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}}}%
    {%
            {\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{name:apa:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}?}}
            {\usebibmacro{name:apa:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}}}%
    {}{}%

    \bibliography{bibli.bib}

    \begin{document}

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Other features may be modified in the same way. The method is always the same: identify the macros that are, as a last resort, responsible for the formatting you want to change and patch it. This supposes you look deep into the .bbx (for bibliography formatting) or .cbx (for citations formatting) files.

Comment: I guess I have all the tools to make it work now, I'll see what I can do, thanks.