# No bibdata command

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I install Linux Mint and setup `latex` anew, but now when I compile latex files I get the following error:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: proposal.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file proposal.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file proposal.aux (There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

The only solution I found was to include the following line:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-plain]{biblatex}
```

But then I had to exclude the line `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, which makes citation looks like **`[Page98]`**, and I want numeric **`[1]`**.

I can install a new [package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo), but I would probably would like to solve the first problem, that is no error for `bibtex` and using `plain` bibliography style. How can I solve the original problem, so that I use `bibtex` instead of `biblatex`?

Here is a snippet of tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-plain]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{url}


\author{Author Name \\
}
\title{Proposal 
}
\date{\today}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\textit{Influence Maximization}, defined by Kempe et al. (2003) \cite{Kempe03}, is the problem of selecting a set of seed nodes in a social graph that maximizes spread of influence under certain cascade model. Being NP-hard for most common cascade models, Kempe et al. propose a natural greedy solution with approximation guarantees that are within 63\% of the optimal. This work led to extensive research on algorithmic and data mining techniques for solving different aspects of the problem. These aspects include, for example, estimation of influence of nodes (propagation probabilities), study of different cascade models, or speed improvement of original greedy solution. In fact, the latter resulted in heuristics Chen et al. (2009, 2010)  \cite{Chen09,Chen10} that are able to reduce running time by more than six order of magnitude of greedy approach with almost no loss of influence spread.  It makes possible to find feasible solutions for large-scale social networks where traditional algorithms fail. 
\end{abstract}

\nocite{spielman08}
\nocite{lafon06}
\nocite{kernelmethods04}
\nocite{concentration_book}
\nocite{spectral_algorithms}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{Kempe03}
D.~Kempe, J.~Kleinberg, and E.~Tardos.
\newblock Maximizing the spread of influence through a social network.
\newblock In {\em Proc.
of the Ninth ACM Int. Conf. on Knowledge Discovery and
Data Mining (KDD’03)}.

\bibitem{Chen09}
W.~Chen, Y.~Wang, and S.~Yang.
\newblock Efficient influence
maximization in social networks.
\newblock In {\em Proc. of the 15th ACM
Int. Conf. on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining
(KDD’09)}.

\bibitem{Chen10}
W.~Chen, Y.~Yuan, and L.~Zhang.
\newblock Scalable influence maximization in social networks under the linear threshold model.
\newblock In {\em ICDM,} pages 88-97, 2010.

\bibitem{Goyal12}
A.~Goyal, F.~Bonchi, L.~V.~Lakshmanan, and S.~Venkatasubramanian.
\newblock On minimizing budget and time in influence propagation over social networks.
\newblock In {\em Social Network Analysis and Mining,} pages 1-14, 2012.

\bibitem{Zhang14}
P.~Zhang, W.~Chen, X.~Sun,Y.~Wang, and J.~Zhang.
\newblock Minimizing Seed Set Selection with Probabilistic Coverage Guarantee in a Social Network.
\newblock {\em Preprint arXiv.org}, 2014.

\bibitem{Domingos01}
P.~Domingos, M.~Richardson.
\newblock Mining the network value of
customers.
\newblock {\em Proceedings of the seventh ACM SIGKDD international conference on knowledge discovery and data mining, ACM, New York, NY, USA, KDD ’01,} pp 57-66, 2001.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you use `thebibliography` environment, you don't need to use `bibtex`. Juat compile two times using, say , `pdflatex`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Please, an answer

Answer (score 12):

When you use the  `thebibliography` environment, you don't need to use `bibtex`. The styling of bib items is solely your responsibility. Just compile two times using, say, `pdflatex` (or whatever you are using).

For `bibtex` (or `biber` with `biblatex`) you have to use a bibliography database (a separate file with `.bib` extension containing the entries, say `mybibfile.bib`) and then use

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybibfile}   %% the .bib file without extension
\end{document}
```

Now compile this file with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: I spent two hours on this bug. Finally I found the correct answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the command `\bibliography{}` in MAC reads the `.bib` file with and without extension whereas Windows cannot find the `.bib` file with extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the configuration setting, in the quick build command. If you are not using BibTeX file then don't include `bibtex`. Try to set it to `PDFlatex` + `View PDF` only.