# Field "fjournal" instead of "journal", if present

Tags: bibtex

I have a bib file that contains entries without a field named `fjournal` and other entries that contain both an `fjournal` and a `journal` field.  I'd like to use a bibliography exactly as in style "plain" but with the contents of field `journal` replaced by the field `fjournal` whenever such a field exists.
Is this possible?

Many thanks!!

Requested example:
Here a shortened example. The field usually appears in the bibtex format of http://www.ams.org/mref .

```
@article{x,
AUTHOR = {Jacod, J. and Protter, P. and xx, y.},
TITLE = {Semimartingales and {M}arkov processes},
JOURNAL = {Z. Wahrsch. Verw. Gebiete},
FJOURNAL = {Zeitschrift f\"ur Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und Verwandte Gebiete},
VOLUME = {54},
YEAR = {1980},
NUMBER = {2},
MRCLASS = {60G44 (60J25)},
MRNUMBER = {597337 (82h:60084)}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I edited the question.  Sorry for the formatting. @Mico

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks as though `fjournal` is being used as a key for the full journal name, while `journal` is being used for abbreviated names.  Since abbreviations should be done separately, I guess I would manually change all the `journal` entries to `ajournal` or something and then change your `fjournal` to `journal`.

Comment: @AlanMunn - I was able to come up with a solution that checks automatically if a field named `fjournal` is present (and, if so, uses it instead of the field named `journal`) in entries of type `@article`.

Comment: @Mico yes that's a simple solution. This would also be something that `biblatex` should be able to do in a much more general way.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Let's see if one or more of the biblatex experts that frequent this site can come up with `biblatex`-based solution. It's always good to have more than one solution method.

Comment: @Mico  This is a great solution, many thanks!!

Comment: @User1234 - You're most welcome! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the adjustments to the bibliography style file that are needed to achieve your objective aren't that difficult to implement. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, and name the copy, say, `plainfj.bst`. Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `plainfj.bst` in the text editor of your choice; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the open file, locate the list named ENTRY; it starts on line 11 in my copy of the file. The items in the list are *all* the field names that the bibliography style recognizes. I suggest you (a) create a new line between the fields named `editor` and `howpublished` and (b) insert the word `fjournal` on the new line.

  Clearly, we first need to tell BibTeX about the existence of a field named `fjournal` if BibTeX is supposed to do something with it later on.
- This "later on" happens to be in the function named `article`. Thus, locate the function named `article` in the file `plainfj.bst`. If you created a new line in the preceding step, the `article` function should start on line 539 of the file.
- In the `article` function, locate the line that looks like this:

  ```
      { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
  ```

  Replace this line with the following four [4] lines:

  ```
      { fjournal missing$
        { journal emphasize "journal" output.check }
        { fjournal emphasize "fjournal" output.check }
        if$
  ```

  Even if you're not familiar with BibTeX's infix syntax, you can probably guess what's going on: In the original version, the field named `journal` is passed to the `emphasize` function, followed by a call to the `output.check` function. (I think you can guess what the `emphasize` function does; the `output.check` function issues a warning if the field -- here: `journal`--  is present but is either empty or present in duplicate.) In the modified version, we first run a test to check if a field named `fjournal` is missing. If it is missing, the old code is run; if it's not missing, the contents of `fjournal` are passed to the `emphasize` and `output.check` functions.
- Save the file `plainfj.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- Start using the new bibliography file by replacing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plain}` with `\bibliographystyle{plainfj}`. Be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTEX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{x,
  AUTHOR   = {{\c C}inlar, E. and Jacod, J. and Protter, P. and Sharpe, M. J.},
  TITLE    = {Semimartingales and {M}arkov processes},
  JOURNAL  = {Z. Wahrsch. Verw. Gebiete},
  FJOURNAL = {Zeitschrift f\"ur Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und Verwandte Gebiete},
  VOLUME   = {54},  
  YEAR     = {1980},
  NUMBER   = {2},
  pages    = {161-219},
  MRCLASS  = {60G44 (60J25)},
  MRNUMBER = {597337 (82h:60084)},
}
@article{y,
  AUTHOR   = {{\c C}inlar, E. and Jacod, J. and Protter, P. and Sharpe, M. J.},
  TITLE    = {Semimartingales and {M}arkov processes},
  JOURNAL  = {Z. Wahrsch. Verw. Gebiete},
  VOLUME   = {54},  
  YEAR     = {1980},
  NUMBER   = {2},
  pages    = {161-219},
  MRCLASS  = {60G44 (60J25)},
  MRNUMBER = {597337 (82h:60084)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plainfj}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With `biblatex` and Biber you can use the source mapping feature

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=fjournal]
      \step[fieldset=journal, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

Which will copy the contents of the `fjournal` field to the `journal` field.

While `numeric` is similar to `plain`, there are styles that emulate `plain` in all details. [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58152/35864)

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{x,
  AUTHOR   = {{\c C}inlar, E. and Jacod, J. and Protter, P. and Sharpe, M. J.},
  TITLE    = {Semimartingales and {M}arkov processes},
  JOURNAL  = {Z. Wahrsch. Verw. Gebiete},
  FJOURNAL = {Zeitschrift f\"ur Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und Verwandte Gebiete},
  VOLUME   = {54},  
  YEAR     = {1980},
  NUMBER   = {2},
  pages    = {161-219},
  MRCLASS  = {60G44 (60J25)},
  MRNUMBER = {597337 (82h:60084)},
}
@article{y,
  AUTHOR   = {{\c C}inlar, E. and Jacod, J. and Protter, P. and Sharpe, M. J.},
  TITLE    = {Semimartingales and {M}arkov processes},
  JOURNAL  = {Z. Wahrsch. Verw. Gebiete},
  VOLUME   = {54},  
  YEAR     = {1980},
  NUMBER   = {2},
  pages    = {161-219},
  MRCLASS  = {60G44 (60J25)},
  MRNUMBER = {597337 (82h:60084)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=trad-plain, backend=biber]{biblatex}% (or style=numeric)

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=fjournal]
      \step[fieldset=journal, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}%
  \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
  \printfield{journalsubtitle}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

But you don't even have to use `biblatex` to use that feature. You can let Biber pre-process your `.bib` file.

Create a file called `biber.conf` with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="fjournal"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="journal" map_origfieldval="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Then run Biber in its tool mode on your `.bib` file, if it is called `fjourn.bib` you would run

```
biber --tool fjourn.bib
```

you get a new file `fjourn_bibertool.bib` where the `fjournal` field is copied to the `journal` field. You can then use `fjourn_bibertool.bib` in your document.