# How to compress the bibliography of LNCS template without changing the source bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I am using the Lecture Note in Computer Science (LNCS) LATEX template, and want to compress the bibliography to a shorter form.

Given bibliographystyle is:

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
```

I want to compress the current output:

> [1] Nguyen, H.H., David, C., Qin, S., Chin, W.: Automated verification
>   of shape and size properties via separation logic. In: Verification,
>   Model Checking, and Abstract Interpretation, 8th International
>   Conference, VMCAI 2007, Nice, France, January 14-16, 2007,
>   Proceedings. pp. 251–266 (2007)

To a shorter form (in this case, abbreviate the conference name)

> [1] Nguyen, H.H., David, C., Qin, S., Chin, W.: Automated verification
>   of shape and size properties via separation logic. VMCAI 2007,
>   Proceedings. pp. 251–266 (2007)

Is there any way to automatically do it without modifying the Bib file?

All of my bibtex are copied from DBLP website. The bibtex for the above bibliography is:

```
@inproceedings{NguyenDQC07,
  author    = {Huu Hai Nguyen and
               Cristina David and
               Shengchao Qin and
               Wei{-}Ngan Chin},
  title     = {Automated Verification of Shape and Size Properties Via Separation
               Logic},
  booktitle = {Verification, Model Checking, and Abstract Interpretation, 8th International
               Conference, {VMCAI} 2007, Nice, France, January 14-16, 2007, Proceedings},
  pages     = {251--266},
  year      = {2007},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-540-69738-1_18},
  timestamp = {Tue, 08 Jan 2008 08:53:10 +0100},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/vmcai/NguyenDQC07},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
```

Thank you very much for taking time looking at my long question!

Comment: The question here is how you propose to tell LaTeX to extract exactly `VMCAI 2007, Proceedings` from `{Verification, Model Checking, and Abstract Interpretation, 8th International Conference, {VMCAI} 2007, Nice, France, January 14-16, 2007, Proceedings}` without changing the `.bib` file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I realize that it is ... too difficult to do so.
Is there anyway compress the bibliography with minimal modification of `bib` file?

Comment: In your example I don't see much room for improvement. The only thing that could be better is the `booktitle` field in the `.bib` file. You should never trust downloaded `.bib` files, often they are not as good as they could be and some manual re-working is necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I have to revise them manually. But my point is that I want to have a set of bibliography, and whenever I need a short format or long format, I can export them with minimal changes of the bibliography. It would be convenient to have this feature. :-)

Comment: Well, you could go down a way like `fjournal` vs. `journal` in [Field “fjournal” instead of “journal”, if present](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272164/35864).

Comment: This is a smart way to do. Thanks for your prompt comment! :-)